# Объединить вложенные списки Python

Tags: python

Есть 2 таких списка

```
mobil = [[{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'}], [{'VALUE': '79265759595', 'VALUE_TYPE': 
'MOBILE'}], 
 [{'VALUE': '79168545921', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'}], [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 
'MOBILE'}], 
[{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'}], [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'}]]

work = [[{'VALUE': '74956318787', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}, {'VALUE': '89290215777', 
'VALUE_TYPE': 
'WORK'}, {'VALUE': '89992228877', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}], [{'VALUE': '+79265759595', 
'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}], [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}], [{'VALUE': None, 
'VALUE_TYPE': 
'WORK'}], [{'VALUE': '+74953630290', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}]]
```

Хочу получить вот такой

```
phone = [[{'VALUE': '74956318787', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}, {'VALUE': '89290215777', 
'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}, {'VALUE': '89992228877', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}, {'VALUE': None, 
'VALUE_TYPE': 
'MOBILE'}],[{'VALUE': '+79265759595', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}, {'VALUE': '79265759595', 
'VALUE_TYPE':'MOBILE'}], [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}, {'VALUE': '79168545921', 
'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'}], [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE':'WORK'}, {'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 
'MOBILE'}]......
```

Как мне его получить?

Comment: Скорее всего, необходимо уточнить, по какому принципу происходит объединение списков.

Comment: Да, что-то принцип совсем непонятен.

Comment: т.е. из списка mobil первый вложенные список должен объединиться с первым вложенным списком из списка work

Comment: А с чем именно возникли сложности? Вопрос в том, как объединить два списка?

Comment: @Сергей, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
res = [m if m[0]["VALUE"] else w for m,w in zip(mobil, work)]
```

результат:

```
In [28]: res
Out[28]:
[[{'VALUE': '74956318787', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'},
  {'VALUE': '89290215777', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'},
  {'VALUE': '89992228877', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}],
 [{'VALUE': '79265759595', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'}],
 [{'VALUE': '79168545921', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'}],
 [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}],
 [{'VALUE': '+74953630290', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}]]
```

или так, если нужны записи из обоих списков (без условий):

```
In [29]: [m+w for m,w in zip(mobil, work)]
Out[29]:
[[{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'},
  {'VALUE': '74956318787', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'},
  {'VALUE': '89290215777', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'},
  {'VALUE': '89992228877', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}],
 [{'VALUE': '79265759595', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'},
  {'VALUE': '+79265759595', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}],
 [{'VALUE': '79168545921', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'},
  {'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}],
 [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'},
  {'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}],
 [{'VALUE': None, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'MOBILE'},
  {'VALUE': '+74953630290', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}]]
```